# ElasticSearch-based problem when starting Sonarqube: 944 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for IfFileName

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

I've recently unpacked sonarqube-8.1.0.31237, installed Oracle Java 11 SDK, set Environment Parameters for `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`. When I try to start sonarqube, several errors are logged regarding ElasticSearch. 
At sonarqube website, it recommends deleting es6 directory and starting it again but it doesn't work.

Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...

Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

Log

```
    2020.01.31 10:43:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\EclUtil\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\temp
    2020.01.31 10:43:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
    2020.01.31 10:43:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [D:\EclUtil\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\EclUtil\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=D:\EclUtil\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=D:\EclUtil\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\sonarqube-8.1.0.31237\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
    2020.01.31 10:43:14 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
    2020.01.31 10:43:15 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
    2020.01.31 10:43:15 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]

    2020-01-31 10:43:16,944 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for IfFileName
    2020-01-31 10:43:16,991 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for IfAccumulatedFileCount
    2020-01-31 10:43:16,991 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for IfFileName
    2020-01-31 10:43:16,991 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class
```